# Authorisation error when request associated builder begin collection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit, healthkit

I am working on an activity tracker for watch OS. I would like to be able to read the heart rate data using Healthkit. The app is written in Objective C and for this particular task there are not so many code examples out there.

From reading the Apple documentation and watching the 2018 WWDC video "New Ways to Work With Workouts" I've coded what I think should work in Objective C. Everything seems to be working fine until I get to the point where I call builder to beginCollectionWithStartDate. The completion handler returns an error: Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Not authorized" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Not authorized}

This is surprising to me, because I can see that on the iOS device under Settings>Privacy>Health>myAppName the permissions look OK. The authorisation process, whereby the Watch app triggers the prompt on the iOS device to approve the requested Healthstore access runs as described in Apple's documentation and as shown on the aforementioned video.

I've tried this on the simulator and on a real watch with paired phone.

Can anyone please help? I'm pulling my hair out with this one!

Here is the relevant Objective C Code that I've written to get to this point (perhaps I've missed something?).

On the watch extension:

Request for authorisation (handled by iOS app)

```
// awakeWithContext

if (!appHasStarted) {

    healthStore = [HKHealthStore new];

    [healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[self dataTypesToShare] readTypes:[self dataTypesToRead]  completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error:requestAuthorizationToShareTypes: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }];
}

- (IBAction)watchStartButtonPressed {

NSLog(@"Pressed start button on watch");

if (watchStartButtonState == startbuttonstatestart) {

    dateWhenPressedStart = [NSDate date];

    configuration = [[HKWorkoutConfiguration alloc] init];

    [configuration setActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeCycling];

    NSError *error;

    workoutSession = [[HKWorkoutSession alloc] initWithHealthStore:healthStore configuration:configuration error:&error];

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Error:unable to establish a workout session: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

        return;
    }

    workoutSession.delegate = self;

    builder = workoutSession.associatedWorkoutBuilder;

    builder.delegate = self;

    HKLiveWorkoutDataSource* dataSource = [[HKLiveWorkoutDataSource alloc] initWithHealthStore:healthStore workoutConfiguration:configuration];

    builder.dataSource = dataSource;

    [workoutSession startActivityWithDate:dateWhenPressedStart];

    [builder beginCollectionWithStartDate:dateWhenPressedStart completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error:beginCollectionWithStartDate: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }];


//This is the point where I get the error message.

- (NSSet *) dataTypesToShare
{
    HKQuantityType *heartRate = [HKQuantityType      quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];
    HKQuantityType *energy = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned];
    HKQuantityType *distance = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling];

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:heartRate,energy,distance,nil];

}

- (NSSet *)dataTypesToRead
{
    HKQuantityType *heartRate = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];
    HKQuantityType *energy = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned];
    HKQuantityType *distance = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling];

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:heartRate,energy,distance,nil];
}
```

Comment: Found solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize for share workout type, swift example:

```
let workoutType = HKObjectType.workoutType()
try await healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [workoutType],
                                                   read: healthKitTypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For future readers. Add this to your Watch Extension plist.

Answer (score 0):

For future "future" readers. I did what Matin De Simone did, but what finally solved my problem was that I had toggle on privacy settings in my health app on my IOS device to allow my WatchOS app to read health data.